# 'require': cannot load such file --mysql ( LoadError )

Tags: mysql, ruby, require

When I attempt to run a ruby file " ruby DisplayWishes.rb " I receive a require load error.
I installed the following mysql packages to see if it would help and currently nothing worked:

```
 sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql
 sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql2

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require':cannot load such file -- mysql(LoadError) 
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
 from DisplayWishes.rb:3:in '<main>'
```

When I attempted to gem install mysql & mysql2

```
sudo gem install mysql2
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.15.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: did you install MySQL gem and MySQL Server?

Comment: I have mysql server installed, I dont think I have mysql gem installed.

Comment: And just to let you know, its not ruby on rails.

Comment: do `gem install mysql && gem install mysql2`

Comment: I received a error when trying to install both. extconf.rb failed - could not create makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. check the mkmf.log file for more details. you may need configuration options

Comment: Paste that error - btw, you should be using mysql2, mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Okay, I pasted the error into the post.

Comment: Try installing libmysqlclient-dev if you are on debian/ubuntu or mysql-devel if you are on centos/redhat.

Comment: okay, that worked. Im now able to complete the gem install, and when I run the ruby script I am presented with new errors but very different unlike the first one.

Comment: If they are unrelated to mysql post New question with it and I will paste earlier comment as answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on freebsd, and got the needed libraries installed by running:

```
pkg_add -rv mysql56-client
```

I was then able to install the mysql and mysql2 gems.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to mysql client is missing.

Install following client the issue will resolve

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```